# How to port jaxb annotation to simpleXml library?

Tags: java, android, annotations, jaxb, simple-framework

I am using Simple xml library to port Jaxb annotations into android.
http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php

I came accross this annotations in jaxb **@XmlRegistry @XmlElementDecl** and I have to convert it into simple xml annotations. Do u have any idea ?? Also how to port **JAXBElement** class into simpleXml's class??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

anddev17_s, to answer your question straight. No you cannot just convert a JAX-B detail class into SimpleXml detail class.

JAX-B and Simple are two different framework. So you need to make changes to the annotation in your existing JAX-B class and put an Simple equivalent annotations or you can just develop a new Simple compliant detail class [refer here](http://jeremyblythe.blogspot.in/2009/11/converting-from-jaxb-to-simple-xml.html).!

For more details on SimpleXml annotations [refer here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php).!

And there is no exact equivalent for

```
@XmlRegistry @XmlElementDecl
```

but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078850/xmlregistry-how-does-it-work) is a detail explanation for these annotations

It would have been easier to answer if you had posted a sample Xml but still you can [refer here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/examples.php) for SimpleXml examples which can shed some light on your migration.